# Why does settings not display a network list of routers?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

When looking for a list of routers none are displayed. I've opened the menu in the right upper corner. The first two controls are volume and brightness. The next control is vpn off. When I open that I find connect and VPN settings. If I click on connect nothing happens. If I open VPN settings I'm faced with a screen that says wired, vpn and network proxy. I have no idea what to do with that screen.

On my other computers there are generally a list of networks listed among which should appear Gilbert 2.5, and Gilbert 5.0 and a list of neighbor networks. However, there is no list, no observable networks at all, and I'm wondering if my network card has been activated by Ubuntu drivers?

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 1420.  It was a Windows machine but I have Ubuntu 20.4 with a clean install. Computer service is Neubeam, the router is Columbia Networks model no.REG-PL-R195W.

Comment: If what you select is an active and working wifi card then yes you will see wifi networks that are close and not hidden. So it seems that is not the icon you have selected. What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks for responding David. It is ver. 20.4